# Which part or quote in Cicero is Greene referring to?

Tags: quote-source, robert-greene, gwydonius-the-carde-of-fancie, cicero, tusculan-disputations

In Robert Greene's novel *Gwydonius; The Carde of Fancie*, one of the characters, Castania, uses the following words in her rejection of Gwydonius (italics from the origin; bold by me):

> Better it is *Gwydonius*, to live in griefe, then to die desperately without grace: better to choose a lingering life in miserie, then a speedie death without mercie, better to be tormented with haplesse fancie, the with hellish fiends, for in life it is possible to redresse miserie. ***Tully***, *Gwydonius*, in his ***Tusculans* questions**, discoursing of the happinesse of life and heavinesse of death, saith, that **to live we obtaine it of the loving Gods, but to dye, of the unluckie destinies**: meaning heereby, that life though never so loathsome, is better than death, though never so welcome: whereby I conclude *Gwydonius*, that to live carefully, is better than to die desperately.

The combination of "Tully" and "Tusculans" makes clear that Castania is referring to Cicero's [*Tusculanae Disputationes* or *Tusculan Disputations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tusculanae_Disputationes), but it is not clear whether she is quoting (more or less accurately) a specific passage or summarizing a larger section (or even a more general idea expressed in *Tusculanae Disputationes*. My [first](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22Tusculan+Disputations%22+live+gods+die+destinies&t=canonical&ia=web) [searches](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22Tusculanae+Disputationes%22+live+gods+die+destinies&t=canonical&ia=web) did not make me any wiser.